# Unknown Parameter Value when attempting to run Access query

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to run a query in MS Access (using the ANSI 92/T-SQL compliant syntax option) 
that (I hope) will remove duplicate values in my table, which are duplicated by Branch Rep ID. The end goal of this query is to be left with records that each have a unique Branch Rep ID, which will in turn mean that each reacord in my table is unique, since Branch rep ID is the only duplicated field.

I am getting the typical pop-up box in MS Access asking for me to define a column value because it doesn't recognize one that I have entered. I have double checked all the column names however, and they are all spelled/spaced/bracketed[] correctly (to my knowledge)

I am stuck and sure could use some help.

Here is a screenshot of the issue:
[image: Screengrab]

Also, here is the actual code I am stuck on:

```
DELETE  DTP_ALL_ALIASES.*
FROM DTP_ALL_ALIASES
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
        SELECT min([branch rep id]) as RowID, [CRD number], [Name First], [Name Last] , Dealer, [Dealer Name], Dealerbrch, [Phone Office Nbr], [Phone Fax Nbr], [Email Address], [Primary Addr Type], 
        [Primary Address 1], [Primary Address 2], [Primary Branch], [Primary City],     [Primary St],  Cntry,   [Primary Zip]        
        FROM DTP_ALL_ALIASES AS dtp 
        Group by  [CRD number], [Name First], [Name Last] , Dealer, [Dealer Name],  Dealerbrch, [Phone Office Nbr], [Phone Fax Nbr], [Email Address], [Primary Addr Type], 
        [Primary Address 1], [Primary Address 2], [Primary Branch], [Primary City],     [Primary St], Cntry, [Primary Zip]        
        ) 
as KeepRows ON
   DTP_ALL_ALIASES.[branch rep id] = KeepRows.RowId
WHERE
   KeepRows.RowId IS NULL
```

EDIT: I believe the T-SQL tag is appropriate here because this Access DB uses the SQL Server Compatible Syntax (ANSI 92) option.

Comment: I thought it might be the extra spaces after the [ `[   Email Address]`  but the image looks like they don't appear in the actual query?

Comment: They don't, it's just a strange formatting issue with SO I think. I fixed all the code to show no spaces.

Comment: `DTP_ALL_ALIASES` is a table or a query?

Comment: As an aside, you really only need the `min([branch rep id]) as RowID` in the select for your `KeepRows`.

Comment: Do you have MS Access? If so, look at the query in design view, it should show you the problem. BTW spaces in field/column names are not good practice.

Comment: I didn't put the the space there, it's a dump from a DB2 database. Also, I clearly state that I am using MS Access in the first line of my question. I doubt that the query can be represented in design view, but I will give out a try anyways on Monday.

Comment: Assuming a linked table, right click and bring up the table in design mode (you answer yes to the prompt telling you this is a linked table and thus design mode is read only). This will give you a list of the column names - pay close attention to what the actual email column name is.

Comment: It's not a linked table, but I did open up the imported table. Like I ssaid before, all the columns are spelled and spaced correctly in my SQL query. The names of the columns in the table match the names of the columns in my SQL script, space for space, letter for letter.